# React JS proper way to set a loader UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, graphql

I was trying to replicate my local project within Code Sandbox and I found my mistake. What I am trying to do in these projects is show a loader spinner while fetching some data from a Express + GraphQL server, but instead, the loader won't hide when the data is loaded.

This is the code where I fetch the data:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useContext, useState } from "react";
import GlobalContext from "../../context/Global/context";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { useLazyQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";

const GET_USERS = gql`
  query {
    users {
      id
      name
      address {
        street
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default props => {
  const globalContext = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const [getUsers, { called, loading, data: users }] = useLazyQuery(GET_USERS);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(globalContext.loading)
    if (globalContext.loading && users.length) {
      globalContext.setLoading(false);
    }
  }, [globalContext, users]);

  if (called && loading) {
    globalContext.setLoading(true);
  }

  if (!users) {
    return <p>There are no users</p>;
  }
  console.log(users)

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Street</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {users.map(user => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{user.id}</td>
              <td>{user.name}</td>
              <td>{user.address.street}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

And this is the code where I set up the Loader:

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-boost";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { HttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import Users from "./components/Users";
import GlobalContext from "./context/Global/context";
import Loader from "react-loader-spinner";

const cache = new InMemoryCache();
const link = new HttpLink({
  uri: "https://73rcp.sse.codesandbox.io/"
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache
});

export default () => {
  const globalContext = useContext(GlobalContext);

  if (globalContext.loading) {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          width: "100vw",
          height: "100vh",
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center"
        }}
      >
        <Loader type="Puff" />
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Users />
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
};
```

#### [This is the frontend code](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-star-w3stp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

#### [This is the backend code](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-glitter-73rcp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

I always have the same issue, not sure what I am doing wrong, but I guess it's because when I set `globalContext.setLoading(true)` the component rerenders and the first component *App.js* loads before than **Users** component.

If this is the error or not, what is the proper way to set a loader spinner while fetching any data from anywhere? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some debugging, the main problem was that `Users` component was unmounting before receiving the data from the server. Also, I encountered some naming conflicts.

```
// App.js
export default () => {
  const globalContext = useContext(GlobalContext);
  // This is making the Users component unmount which won't allow to change the
  // global loading state once the data is received, hence the perpetual loading.
  if (globalContext.loading) {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          width: "100vw",
          height: "100vh",
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center"
        }}
      >
        <Loader type="Puff" />
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Users />
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
};
```

A simple fix would be to render both the `Loader` and the Users component, however, the former will be positioned absolutely so the user can't interact with the `Users` component.

```
export default () => {
  const globalContext = useContext(GlobalContext);

  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Users />
      {globalContext.loading && (
        <div
          style={{
            width: "100vw",
            height: "100vh",
            display: "flex",
            position: "absolute",
            top: 0,
            backgroundColor: "white",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center"
          }}
        >
          <Loader type="Puff" />
        </div> 
      )}
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
};
```

On the `Users` component there were some issues:

```
// Users component
export default props => {
  const globalContext = useContext(GlobalContext);
  // data: users will not return users object, instead it is only renaming it. 
  // if we were to destructure it like data: { users }, an error would be thrown since 
  // data.users is undefined. 
  const [getUsers, { called, loading, data: users }] = useLazyQuery(GET_USERS);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, [getUsers]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // data does not contain a length property since it is an object. Again an 
    // error would be thrown. 
    if (globalContext.loading && users.length) {
      globalContext.setLoading(false);
    }
  }, [globalContext, users]);

  if (called && loading) {
    globalContext.setLoading(true);
  }

  if (!users) {
    return <p>There are no users</p>;
  }

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Street</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {/* Since data is not an array, map would be undefined (error again)*/}
        {users.map(user => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{user.id}</td>
              <td>{user.name}</td>
              <td>{user.address.street}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

So to fix this we have:

```
export default props => {
  const globalContext = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const [getUsers, { called, loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(GET_USERS);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, [getUsers]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (globalContext.loading && data) {
      globalContext.setLoading(false);
    }
  }, [globalContext, data]);

  if (called && loading) {
    globalContext.setLoading(true);
  }

  if (!data) {
    return <p>There are no users</p>;
  }

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Street</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {data &&
          data.users.map(user => {
            return (
              <tr>
                <td>{user.id}</td>
                <td>{user.name}</td>
                <td>{user.address.street}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

All changes are in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-flower-eqhbk).

Comment: Thank you, inserting the Loader inside the component's render made the trick.

Answer (score -2):

There are multiple ways to implement loader in react app while getting data or sending some data from/to server.

The best way is to create a higher order component that will load the wrapping feature component or a loader based on a Boolean flag.